# Ubuntu + TrueCrypt + Dropbox + Desktop PC with WIndows 7 + Netbook with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, dropbox, truecrypt

I have two PCs, a netbook running Ubuntu 12.04 and a desktop running Windows 7. I use Dropbox to share files between the two PCs.

I need to encrypt some files, and I have installed TrueCrypt on both PCs. I can encrypt (and decrypt) the files on my desktop PC and I can see the TrueCrypt file on my netbook, but I do not understand how to decrypt the file I can see on my netbook. And encrypt new files on my netbook to be able to decrypt on my PC.

Can someone point me to an article or give some information (simple terms please, I am new to Ubuntu and TrueCrypt) on **how to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps for a propper installation:

For 32 bit systems:

```
$ wget http://www.truecrypt.org/download/truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x86.tar.gz
```

For 64 bit systems:

```
$ wget http://www.truecrypt.org/download/truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Extract the archive:

```
$ tar -zxvf truecrypt*.gz
```

Install TrueCrypt:

```
$ sudo ./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x86
```

To uninstall TrueCrypt, do this:

```
$ sudo truecrypt-uninstall.sh
```

To run it, just type truecrypt in the terminal:

```
$ sudo truecrypt
```

If you prefer to install from a ppa you can use this one for Ubuntu 12.04 or higher

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-astrapi/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

After installing you need to select "slot" or create volume and "mount" the partitions that have files for encryption.